# Is there any way to check if user has registered once then app should diplay menu directly. If not then above verification screen should be displayed

Tags: android

I have registered a user by sending a verification code at once in whole life cycle.
I want to show user menu directly if he is a registered user.
If not then registration screen should be displayed.
Can you tell me how to do that?
How can I check if user is registered or not and display screen accordingly?

Comment: set the registration code in preference once it received then everytime your app will initiate check for that registration code. If you found that code then display menu directly.

Comment: Sorry. I Didn't get what you said.
Can you tell me any example?

Comment: After Registration done successfully put some value in preference and then check preference that value is available or not in preference if not then user is not registered.

Answer (score 0):

You can store registered boolean value into preferences.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Answer (score 0):

Whenever your user register in your app with verification code store it in sharedpreference.
using this

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

   Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("verification_code", "your code value");
        editor.commit();
```

then whenever user again come to your application on the first screen of your application check

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String code= sharedPreferences.getString("verification_code", "");

        if (code=="") {
            "register activity"
        } else {
           "menu activity"
        }
```

I hope this will help you. 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

you can find other options here. But this is the easiest way to do.